# ASP.NET C# Connect Checkboxex with Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datagrid, datatable

I'm just at a function, which outputs a list of file names from the database. I get this also from the database and store it into a DataTable. The DataTable give the list to a DataGrid, which displays it on the page. That works fine.

My problem is that I want next to each file name have a check box on the right, which I can tick and Next time when I save the form, the database entry will be deleted.

How can I do this so the program dynamically displays the checkbox to the DataTable and the checkbox would know to which entry it has?

Best Regards
Michael Ryter

Comment: Please ask your questions in **English** if you can.. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="Name">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Checkbox id="chkIsDeletable" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField id="hndFileId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("FileID")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="Name">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("filename") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

> > > > Now on button click event:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

String SelectedFileIds ="";
        foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkIsDeletable = item.FindControl("chkIsDeletable") as CheckBox;
            HiddenField hndFileId = item.FindControl("hndFileId") as HiddenField;
            if (chkIsDeletable.Checked)
                SelectedFileIds = hndFileId.Value + ",";
        }
        SelectedFileIds = SelectedFileIds.TrimEnd(",");

}
```

Now you will have all those file ids for which you have ticked the checbox, now you can delete those records from the database which contains selected fileids.

Hope, it will help you!!!